# Binding to background services fails on Android OS 8

Tags: android, service

I need to start a few services provided by other apps, let them execute whatever the want to execute, and kill them once they call me back and I receive the data collected. Sadly `startService(serviceIntent);` crashes with

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{…}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {…}: app is in background uid UidRecord{70fcf01 u0a90 CEM  bg:+1h49m29s56ms idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

It appears that this is by design, [here's the crashing AOSP code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java;l=532?q=%22app%20is%20in%20background%22).

My code crashing looks like this:

```java
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory("my.special.service.CATEGORY");
List<ResolveInfo> results = pm.queryIntentServices(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ResolveInfo info : results) {
  ComponentName name =
      new ComponentName(info.serviceInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, info.serviceInfo.name);
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
  serviceIntent.setComponent(name);
  startService(serviceIntent); //  K A B O O M
  bindService(serviceIntent, boundServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

The way service is defined in another app's Manifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".ServiceFromAnotherApp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <categoy android:name="my.special.service.CATEGORY" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

Any ideas if there're any workarounds, maybe different architecture?

Core trait that I want to retain is:

1. to be able to create a service
2. tell it to fetch additional data (potentially several times during its lifecycle)
3. get callback from the service once it finishes every subsequence fetch

Comment: You are attempting to do this from a background service, correct?

Comment: the snippet of code calling service from the foreground app

Comment: I'm not really buying this. Docs state foreground apps give other apps/services their foreground affinity. Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services), starting with: "An app is considered to be in the foreground if..."